# Call a Proc from another Proc - pl/sql procedure that returns a ref-cursor?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

How do I modify the following syntax so that I can look up and then Execute the the 2 procedures dynamically:
(ic_rep_test1 & ic_rep_test2, which are stored in a table called OPSGENERAL.IC_EXTRACTS ).

I think it's because the proc needs to be called with the ref cursor passed 
in as a parameter?   Not sure how to get it to work dynamically.

Would an 'Execute Immediate' statement work?
Thanks!

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ic_rep_extract_retrieval (
  e_id IN integer,
  exout OUT sys_refcursor
  ) IS

BEGIN

IF e_id = '1' THEN
  ic_rep_test1 (exout);
ELSIF e_id = '2' THEN
  ic_rep_test2 (exout);
END IF;


END ic_rep_extract_retrieval;



/******************************  Revised **************/
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OPSGENERAL.ic_rep_extract_retrieval_dl (
     e_id    IN     INTEGER
    ,exout      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
   IS
    use_proc_name   VARCHAR2 (200);
   BEGIN
     SELECT PROC
        INTO use_proc_name
        FROM OPSGENERAL.IC_EXTRACTS
       WHERE extract_id = e_id;

       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
            'declare exout sys_refcursor; begin '   || use_proc_name   ||       '(exout); end;';
      END ic_rep_extract_retrieval_dl;
   /
```

Comment: Some additional Info: The 2 stored procedures ((ic_rep_test1 & ic_rep_test2) are stored in a table called OPSGENERAL.IC_EXTRACTS with 2 variables 'extract_id' and 'Proc-name').  Thanks!

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OPSGENERAL.ic_rep_extract_retrieval_dl (
   e_id    IN     INTEGER
  ,exout      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
   use_proc_name   VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
   SELECT PROC
     INTO use_proc_name
     FROM OPSGENERAL.IC_EXTRACTS
    WHERE extract_id = e_id;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
         'declare exout sys_refcursor; begin '   || use_proc_name   || '(exout); end;';
END ic_rep_extract_retrieval_dl;
/

Comment: In the 'Revised' SP code above, the syntax compiles without error however it does not generate the results of the proc id #1 when entered by user, it only returns 'procedure executed' .

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand what is meant by  the comment of 'a_horse_with_no_name'?

Comment: In the 'Revised' SP code above, the syntax compiles without error however it does not generate the results of the proc id #1 when entered by user, it only returns 'procedure executed'  with no output results.  Thanks!